# In Android, How to get HTML source code into a String?

Tags: java, android, html

I would like to get the source code from an url. But all things i found, is deprecated or it's no what i want, so i still searching, but i find nothing.

Deprecated :

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); // Create HTTP Client
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://yoururl.com"); // Set the action you want to do
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget); // Executeit
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity(); 
InputStream is = entity.getContent(); // Create an InputStream with the response
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) // Read line by line
    sb.append(line + "\n");

String resString = sb.toString(); // Result is here

is.close(); // Close the stream
```

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Use alternative http client it will be faster and better. I can recommend you this.

https://square.github.io/okhttp/

Answer (score 0):

Try using HttpClient from apache http

```
   class Task extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://www.google.com");
                    httppost.getParams().setBooleanParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USE_EXPECT_CONTINUE, false);
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    HttpEntity resEntity = httpresponse.getEntity();
                    String str = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
                    return str;
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    return ex.getMessage();
                }
            }

            Listener listen;
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                listen.returnVal(result);
            }

        }

    public interface Listener {
        public void returnVal(String str);
    }

public class Activity1 extends ActionBarActivity implements Listener {
...

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
....
Task t = new Task();
        t.listen = this;
        t.execute();
}

@Override
    public void returnVal(String str) {
        // Http Response
    }
```

Don't forget to add `<uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` in your manfiest

Comment: What do you mean with soapAction ? I didn't have that, and all function are deprecated.

Comment: Okay thank you, be careful you the "HttpResponse" paste to the variable: )

Comment: Thanks , please try and tell me.

Comment: I just try, but i'm a novice with Android Studio, and i don't know where is print, do you know ?

Comment: You can user `Log.d(/*message*/)` this print in the cat log, or you can put the result into a textview on your mobile or the testing device.

Comment: Nothing is printed, with the both option :/